# Bigger txt file with less rows on Windows after Powershell Select-String

Tags: windows, file, powershell, size

I applied several filters to a text files using Powershell Get-Content and the -nomatch operator and then i spooled the result to a file.

```
gc file.txt | {?_ -notmatch 'excl1|excl2|excl3'} | out-file newfile.txt
```

What happens is that the output file (newfile.txt) has less lines, but it is reported by windows with a bigger size than file.txt.

Has someone ever encountered this behavior? How can I have the correct size reported by windows? I checked the number of rows, the file with less rows is reported as bigger in size.

Comment: filter a text file (.txt) using several keywords in the format: gc file.txt | ?{$_ -notmatch 'excl1|excl2|excl2'} | out-file newfile.txt. newfile.txt is bigger than file.txt

Comment: ***{?_ -notmatch 'excl1|excl2|excl3'}*** is the filter.

Comment: Give us an example file with your comparing file sizes. .... Also need to know the _encoding_. I am guessing that is where the issue comes from?

Comment: I agree with Matt. The output file is probably larger because `Out-File` creates the file with Unicode encoding (2 bytes per character) whereas the input file most likely is ASCII encoded (1 byte per character).

Comment: Where is `Select-String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm certain you have an encoding issue. By default `Get-Content` uses ascii whereas `Out-File` uses Unicode.

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx)

> -Encoding
>
> Specifies the type of character encoding used in the file. Valid values are "Unicode", "UTF7", "UTF8", "UTF32", "ASCII", "BigEndianUnicode", "Default", and "OEM". **"Unicode" is the default**.

Use `-Enconding ascii` with `Out-File` or just use `Set-Content` as it is the partner of `Get-Content`.

```
Get-Content file.txt | {?_ -notmatch 'excl1|excl2|excl3'} | 
    out-file -Encoding ascii newfile.txt
    # or
    Set-Content newfile.txt
```

Coming from the other direction if you have issues with your input file `Get-Content` in PowerShell v3 and above also supports `-Enconding`